# Use Google Analytics to track users who are logged in and those who are not logged in

Tags: google-analytics

How can I track logged in vs non logged in users in Google Analytics?

Comment: What do you mean by "track"?   Do you want a count of how many of each there are or do you want to see the different behavior of the two types of users?

Answer (score 1):

The recommended approach is to use [custom dimensions and metrics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets). You would need to modify the tracking script to include these additional fields with each hit, which will provide you with the ability to segment the data based on the values of those fields. The example use case that Google Developers provides in the documentation is this same scenario.